# if (isset($_POST[ echo $_POST

Tags: php

I need help with some coding.

I watched some tutorials from W3Schools and youtube, but I just don't get it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Push me"]))

echo $_POST['name']
?>
<html>
<body>
Registration
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" target="_blank">
  Insert name <input type="text" name="fname"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Push me">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When you push the button there should be a name that was typed into the field.

Example:
If you enter the name Simon after pushing the button it should write Hello Simon under the button

Comment: ` (isset($_POST["push_me"]))` that is incorrect. you are checking for value instead of name. this should be `<input type="submit" value="Push me">` = `<input type="submit" name="push_me" value="Push me">`

Comment: You have syntax error (hint: semicolon is required in PHP) in your server side code. Also if you expect the output to appear UNDER the button then your code is not doing that, even after you correct the mistake the output will appear before the beginning of your document body.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["fname"]))
//                ^^^^^

echo $_POST['fname'];
//           ^^^^^  ^

<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" target="_blank">
//                                      ^^^^
```

Comment: Please add a textual explaination why the code in the original question is wrong, and why the above changes are necessary to make the code work. This will help others understand the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your PHP code is out of the HTML tag, I have place the php code in the DIV under the button, i.e. to display "Hello xxxTheNameYouEnterInTheInputxxx"
2. The if condition in your PHP code should be like `if(isset($_POST["fname"]))` instead of `if(isset($_POST["Push me"]))` 
   i.e. $_POST["NameOfTheInputElementInTheForm"]
3. `<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" target="_blank">` should be like `<form action="/test.php" method="POST">` i.e. Method is POST and action should be the name of the file, remove `target="_blank"`

Here is the full code, save it as `test.php`

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Registration
        <form action="/test.php" method="POST">
            Insert Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Push me">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST["fname"])){
                    echo "Hello " . $_POST['fname'];
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: tnx work for me. and a little more logical to me now :)